# W3C Validation - Script Tag - Javascript or Something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, w3c-validation

I'm getting an bunch of errors in w3c validation because a script tag is missing the type attribute.  I have 1 left over that I'm not confident what to do with

My code that doesn't validate:

```
<script>
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

I've changed it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    !window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

I've read that jquery is a framework in javascript, so I'm assuming this is correct above, but is there a different 'type' to use for jquery?

Thans!

Comment: Nope. jQuery is written in javascript so it's the same type.

Comment: What version are you validating against? The type attribute **is** optional in **HTML5**, but not previous versions.

Comment: So what do you really need from here?

Comment: Jai - I was looking for an opinion/answer if I was adding the right type to the script tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using doctype HTML4/XHTML, the type attribute is required.

But if you are using doctype HTML5, it's not required.

More : [W3C Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html)

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you're right. jQuery is definitely Javascript.